# How to Sort Numerically Ascending with scandir()

Tags: php

Just like the question asks.  Does 5.4 address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] )
```

but `SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING` will not work properly with numerical names. You can foreach items and then sort them with other function like this one: `sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

As of version 5.4.0

> sorting_order now accepts constants. Any nonzero value caused descending order in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using scandir();  To make it sort Descending rather than the default Ascending, use the int 1 or 0.

scandir(directory,sort,context);

for example:

```
$dir = "./portfolio"; 
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
```

w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_scandir.asp