# PHP - How to search folder images per order

Tags: php, search, directory

I have the following code to search the folder /images/ for images and echo them. However, it displays the images from a random order everytime I refresh the page. The images are named 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. Any way to make it so that the last number (ex: 4) is the first one being displayed and so on?

```
<?php
    $dirname = "images";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    shuffle($images);
    $ignore = Array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<img src=\"". $dirname . '/' . $curimg ."\">" ;
        }
    }               
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$images = scandir($dirname,1);`
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126032/how-to-sort-numerically-ascending-with-scandir

Comment: @Grmn Don't use 1, but the constant SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING.

Comment: Neither of them work!

Comment: You have removed the `shuffle($images);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to your shuffle. You are randomizing your array. Let me introduce you to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php  which is

```
<?php
    $dirname = "images";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    $images = arsort(array_reverse($images, true));
    $ignore = Array(".", "..");
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo "<img src=\"". $dirname . '/' . $curimg ."\">" ;
        }
    }               
?>
```

---

**Update**:

```
$dirname = "Images";
$images = scandir($dirname);
sort($images,SORT_NUMERIC);
krsort($images);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
foreach($images as $curimg){
    if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
        echo "<img src=\"". $dirname . '/' . $curimg ."\"> \n" ;
    }
}
```

What I have been working with:

Without the `sort();` and `krsort();` i return:

```
<img src="Images/1.png"> 
<img src="Images/10.png"> 
<img src="Images/11.png"> 
<img src="Images/2.png"> 
<img src="Images/3.png"> 
<img src="Images/4.png"> 
<img src="Images/5.png"> 
<img src="Images/6.png"> 
<img src="Images/7.png"> 
<img src="Images/8.png"> 
<img src="Images/9.png">
```

With the krsort and sort.. I return:

```
<img src="Images/11.png"> 
<img src="Images/10.png"> 
<img src="Images/9.png"> 
<img src="Images/8.png"> 
<img src="Images/7.png"> 
<img src="Images/6.png"> 
<img src="Images/5.png"> 
<img src="Images/4.png"> 
<img src="Images/3.png"> 
<img src="Images/2.png"> 
<img src="Images/1.png">
```

Which I presume is what you are looking for.

Comment: natsort is not necessary as scandir already outputs the filenames sorted

Comment: I have re-read the question and updating my answer accordingly

Comment: There's a problem though. It's sorting by 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I'm not really an expert in scripting, could you update the code so that it works correctly? Sorry.

Comment: @coldpumpkin I am just experimenting with things that might work, give my update a update your question with a typical array you expect

Comment: I want like 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

What is happening is 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 22, 21, 20, 2, 19, 18, ...

Comment: Can you explain further... I will replicate your condition providing I get enough information

Comment: Alright, let's imagine I have 30 images inside a folder. I want the code to display the images from 30 to 1, in that specific order.

What is currently happening is that the script isn't respecting the two-number numbers. Basically it is considering that 9 is higher than 30. It guides itself from the starting number.

Here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php
I want the "Natural sorting order" and not the "Standard sorting order".

Comment: So you want it in completely descending order? Sure. Give me a few to knock something up. I will post my findings

Comment: @coldpumpkin Sorry for the delay, it was a tricky thing to work out, because I did not want to introduce an unnecessary function

Comment: Don't worry, it did the trick! It's perfect! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

should be the right function instead of shuffle

UPDATE:

Better would be to sort it directly via scandir:

```
$images = scandir($dirname, SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
```

Comment: Though this is using the "Standard Sorting" and not the "Natural Sorting" which I want. Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: This you hadn't said with any word in the question... (then do something with natsort and then array_reverse)

Comment: `$images = scandir($dirname); natsort($images); $images = array_reverse($images);` or what would you imagine?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load image names into array, than sort array and then echo image tags

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$dirname = "images";
$files = scandir($dirname, 1); // using SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING PHP 5.4+ ONLY!
foreach ($files as $file) {
 if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
     echo "<img src=\"". $dirname . '/' . $file ."\">" ;
}
}
?>
```